# how to see end lines characters inside a textarea?

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I'm creating a simple online text editor and need an option to show end lines characters inside a textarea.

`BR, CR, LF...` whatever is typed by pressing Enter - I need to be visible.

Is it possible?

Thanks.

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
  // show-hide end lines;
});
```

```css
.tx{
display:block;
width: 100%;
resize:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea class='tx' rows = 9>
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum
lorem ipsum


</textarea>
<button>CLICK</button>
```

Comment: it is not clear. Can you please add more description

Comment: @brk - what is not clear? each line has a break character, it should be visible.

Comment: Have you tried encodeURI() ?THat will give you %0A which is the new line.

Comment: If you display a character as line break, it will be a part of your content in textarea.

Comment: @Devloop80, maybe, pls write an example

Comment: @Chaska, it's ok, but click on the button again should hide them, i.e. remove from the content

Comment: But it will encode everything.
Do you want only a symbol at the end of each line...or do you want the last line?

Comment: @Devloop80, I need a symbol at the end of each line. As in any text editor, for example notepad++. Click on an icon shows/hides the symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see is this what you need?

```js
$('#toggle').on('click', function() {
  var txt = $('textarea').val();
  if ($('textarea').attr('data-linebreak') == 'off') {
    txt = txt.replace(/\n/g, '↵\n');
    $('textarea').attr('data-linebreak', 'on');
  } else {
    txt = txt.replace(/↵\n/g, '\n');
    $('textarea').attr('data-linebreak', 'off');
  }
  $('textarea').val(txt);
});
```

```css
textarea {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea data-linebreak="off"></textarea>
<br>
<input type="button" value="Toggle" id="toggle">
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code snippet,  here we are replacing `\n` with new line char.

```
$('button').on('click', function(){
  $('.tx').val(v.replace(/\n/g, '↵\n')) // show end lines char;
});

$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('.tx').val(v.replace(/↵\n/g, '\n')) // hide end lines char;
});
```